# Need help in proving F to be Galois over E

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose f $\in K[x]$  splits in F as $f = (x - u_1)^{n_1} . · · (x - u_k)^{n_k} (u_i  $distinct ;$ n_i > 1)$.
Let $v_0, . . . , v_k$ be the coeficients of the polynomial $g = (x - u_1)(x - u_2) ... (x - u_k)$
and let $E = K(v_0 ... ,v_k)$

(a) F is a splitting field of g over E.

(b) F is Galois over E.

(c) $Aut_E F = Aut_K F$

I have done (a) but  for (b) I need to prove that  fixed field of $  Aut_E F$ is  E itself. but unable to do so. I chose $\sigma  \in Aut_K E$ and and i  need to show that $\sigma (v)= v $ iff $v \in E$ .  But I am not able to get an idea on which result I should use to prove this. Can you please give me some directions.

Comment: If you can briefly explain how you did part $a$, it would be useful.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I did it a really long time ago so I an not able to recollect.

Comment: What is your definition of a separable extension, and of a normal extension? I'm thinking of the usual "polynomial with distinct roots" as a separable polynomial and an extension by the roots of such a polynomial as a separable one, so our definitions don't match, and with mine I feel this is too easy to write down so I'm clarifying. You're using the automorphism one I assume, but can you write it down just so I'm sure we're on the same page?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Let K he a field and $f \in K[x]$ an irreducible polynomial. The polynomial
f is said to be separable if in some splitting field of f over K every root of is a
simple root.
If F is an extension field of K and $u \in F$ is algebraic over K , then u is said to be
separable over K provided its irreducible polynon1ial is separable. If every element of F
is separable over K, then F is said to be a separable extension of K .

Comment: @TeresaLisbon An algebraic extension field F of K is normal over K (or a normal
extension) if every irreducible polynomial in K[x] that has a root in F actually splits
in F[x] .

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If you have any question that is also most welcome.

Comment: I have... no further questions. Only answers. Which I'll try to post as soon as I can! I was just making sure that the definition that we have regarding field automorphisms is clarified. With your definitions in the comments, this looks easier.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks man!

Comment: Just one small thing : make sure you put these definitions into the question itself. Since we interacted a little about the question, that will count as context so we won't need to worry about a lack of it, in case.

Answer (score 2):

###### (a)

We want to prove that $F$ is a splitting field of $g$ over $E$. To prove this, we first observe that the coefficients of $g$ belong in $E$ by definition of $E$, hence $g \in E[X]$, so the splitting field of $g$ over $E$ certainly exists.

Now, the roots of $g$ are precisely $u_1,u_2,...,u_k$, which also happen to precisely be the roots of $F$. Since $F$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$, it follows that $F = K(u_1,...,u_k)$. Using Vieta's formulas, we know that each $v_i$ is a polynomial in $u_1,...,u_k$, therefore $v_i \in F$ for all $i$, which implies that $$K(v_0,...,v_k,u_1,...,u_k) = E(u_1,...,u_k) \subset F = K(u_1,...,u_k) \subset E(u_1,...,u_k)$$

Therefore, $F = E(u_1,...,u_k)$ which makes $F$ a splitting field of $g$ over $E$.

---

###### (b)

Splitting fields are actually Galois by a standard result, but I'll present a more detailed argument anyway.

To prove that $F$ is Galois over $E$, we need to prove that it is a separable and normal extension. Note that $F$ is the splitting field of $g$ over $E$ and $F = E(u_1,...,u_k)$, so it's enough to prove that the minimal polynomial of each of the $u_i$ is separable. But that minimal polynomial *divides* (thank you very much , HeroZhang001 for the correction) $g$ for each $u_i$, and $g$ only has simple roots by definition (since it is not divisible by $(x-u_i)^2$ for any $i$). Thus, the extension is separable quite obviously.

For normality, let $h(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ with a root in $F$,  without loss of generality suppose that $h(u_1) = 0$. We will prove that every root of $h$ lies in $F$, so $h$ splits over $F$, making the extension normal.

Indeed, suppose not. Let $M$ be a splitting field for $h$ over $F[x]$ and let $r \in M$ be a root of $h$. Note that $[K(u_1):K] = [K(r):K]$ since they have the same minimal polynomial which is $h$.

We will now see why $[F(u_1):K(u_1)] = [F(r) : K(r)]$. The point is, that both are splitting fields of $g$ over different base fields : the smallest field containing $K(u_1)$ and all the roots of $g$, is just $F(u_1)$ (which just equals $F$ but we keep the elaborate notation anyway). Similarly, the smallest field containing $K(r)$ and all the roots of $g$ is just $F(r)$. Therefore, both extensions have the same degree i.e. $[F(u_1):K(u_1)] = [F(r):K(r)]$.

Using the tower law, we get that $[F(u_1):K] = [F(r) : K]$. Dividing by $[F:K]$ on both sides yields by the tower law that $[F(u_1):F] = [F(r):F]$. But the LHS is just $1$ : so the RHS is $1$, hence $r \in F$ as desired.

Hence, the extension is separable normal, hence Galois.

---

###### (c)

We want to prove that $Aut_E F = Aut_K F$. By definition, $Aut_L F$ is the set of all automorphisms of $F$ that fix $L$.

Well, since $K \subset E$, any automorphism that fixes $E$ obviously fixes $K$. The reverse has to be proven : if an automorphism of $F$ fixes $K$, then it fixes $E$. Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $F$ that fixes $K$. We claim that $\sigma$ permutes the $u_i$, in the sense that $\sigma(\{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}) = \{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}$.

To prove this, note that $\sigma$ is a homomorphism, therefore for any polynomial $p(x)$ we have $\sigma(p(u)) = p(\sigma(u))$ for $u \in F$. Applying this to $g$, we know that if $u_i$ is a root of $g$, then $$0=\sigma(0) = \sigma(g(u_i)) = g(\sigma(u_i))$$

so $\sigma(u_i)= u_j$ for some $j$. But then, each $u_i$ can correspond only to a unique $u_j$ since $\sigma$ is an automorphism hence one-to-one. The claim follows.

Now, once the claim is done, let $h(u_1,...,u_k)$ be any *symmetric* polynomial in the $u_i$ i.e. which satisfies $h(u_1,...,u_k) = h(u_{\tau(1)},...,u_{\tau(k)})$ for  any $\tau$ which is a permutation of $1,...,k$. It follows from $\sigma$ being a homomorphism that $\sigma(h(u_1,...,u_k)) = h(\sigma(u_1),...,\sigma(u_k))$. But then, what's inside is just a permutation of the $u_i$! So by symmetry of $h$, we get that $\sigma(h(u_1,...,u_k)) = h(u_1,...,u_k)$. In other words : *any polynomial symmetric in the $u_i$ is fixed by $\sigma$*.

Now, are the $v_i$ symmetric polynomials in the $u_i$? Indeed! It's well known via Vieta's formulas that each $v_i$ is a symmetric function of the $u_i$ given by $v_0 = 1$ and $v_l = \pm \sum_{1 \leq k_1 < k_2 <...<k_l \leq k} u_{k_1}...u_{k_l}$ which can be shown to be symmetric in the $u_i$ by exploiting symmetry in the index sets. Thus, it turns out that $\sigma(v_i) = v_i$ for all $i$ : but then $E = K(v_i)$ so $\sigma$ fixes $E$ as well.

Hence, we are done!

Comment: For separablity in (b), why the minimal polynomial is $g$ for each $u_i$?

Comment: @HeroZhang001 Been some time since I wrote this one , so I'll go through it (which usually takes some time) and get back to you. Thank you for your question.

Comment: Thank you! You are very welcome!

Comment: @HeroZhang001 thank you for your patience. I think I'm wrong : $g$ may not be irreducible. But one can still execute the argument : the minimal polynomial of each $u_i$ will still *divide* $g$, which has distinct roots, by the definition of $g$. So whatever the minimal polynomial of $u_i$ is, it will still be separable.does that make sense? If not, I'd be happy to clarify this, but thank you very much for your correction (I'll make it right now).

Comment: There is a theorem in my book: If $F$ is an extension field of $K$, then the following statements are equivalent. 
(i) $F$ is algebraic and Galois over $K$; 
(ii) $F$ is separable over $K$ and $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of a set $S$ of polynomials in $K[x]$; 
(iii) $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of a set $T$ of separable polynomials in $K[x]$.

Comment: I think we should decompose $g$ into the product of irreducible polynomials and use (iii) to (i)

Comment: @HeroZhang001 Sorry for the late response, I was asleep. Indeed, you're right : for each $u_i$, the minimal polynomial $p_{i}$ of $u_i$ over $E$ is a divisor of $g$ hence separable. $F$ is the splitting field of the set of polynomials $p_{i}$ over $E$, because any splitting field must contain all the $u_i$ hence contain $F$ (by part (a)), but then $F$ already contains all the $u_i$ and hence all the roots of every $p_i$ (because the $p_i$ divides $g$ and $F$ contains all the roots of $g$). Therefore, use (iii) to (i) like you said, and you are done.